# Show Tag panel in custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I just made a custom post type. How do I display the **Tag** panel on the sidebar same as what the *Post* post type has?

Comment: can you show me the code you added in then functions.php to create the custom post type ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

add this line to the section you `register_post_type` in functions.php in your theme folder

```
'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')
```

The full code is looks like this

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'posttypename',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'PostTypeName' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'PostTypeName' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'posttypename'),
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
            'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag') // this is IMPORTANT
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for: `'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')`. Thanks, Chandu!

Comment: Man I was looking the whole google than I found this solution , thanks

Answer (score 9):

If you use `'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')` then wordpress default post's tags will be display in the custom post type area.

Here is the clean and unique way for "news" post type.No mixing with other custom post types,default tags,..etc.

You can follow full details of ["create custom post types and tags with categories" from this link.](http://webexplorar.com/wordpress-create-custom-post-types-with-tags-and-categories/)

```
add_action( 'init', 'news_tag_taxonomies' ); //change order add_action( 'init', 'news_tag_taxonomies', 0 );

//create two taxonomies, genres and tags for the post type "tag"
function news_tag_taxonomies() 
{
  // Add new taxonomy, NOT hierarchical (like tags)
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Tags', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Tag', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Tags' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Tags' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Tags' ),
    'parent_item' => null,
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Tag' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Tag' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Tag' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Tag Name' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate tags with commas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove tags' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used tags' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Tags' ),
  ); 

  register_taxonomy('tag','news',array( // replace your post type with "news"
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tag' ),
  ));
}
```

Hope this would be help.

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to add apart from default WP codex template was

```
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
```