# How to add tags in Wordpress Custom Post?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I created a custom post but there is no tags available unlike the default post in the WORDPRESS which have tags. How can I copy or implement that in the custom post I created?

Please kindly give me tips.

My custom post and there's no tags available
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can go to your "Screen options" at the top right and tick Tags to make it visible.
http://en.support.wordpress.com/screen-options/ or you can refer this stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245071/show-tag-panel-in-custom-post-type

Comment: I already tried but it's on... and if I go to the post(default not the custom) it visible.

Comment: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/07/custom-post-type-with-categories-post.html
You can put those codes in functions.php (in your theme folder)

Comment: thanks men.. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Add this section in your custom post type

$args = array('labels' => $labels,'public' => true,'publicly_queryable' => true,'show_ui' => true,'query_var' => true,'rewrite' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => false,'menu_position' => null,'taxonomies' => array('tag') );