# Wordpress - Query Posts by Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm looking to query my posts via a custom field that I've created on my page. But the custom field is an array of values. So the custom field 'country' could look like this

country => usa,africa,united kingdom,poland

What's confusing me is how to query posts with a custom field which is an array seperated with ','?

I've tried quite a few solutions on here with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you write "usa,africa,united kingdom,poland" as the value for one key?

That would be a string and not an array.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't it need to be separated out if I was writing a custom query for tags?

Comment: Is their a reason you don't want to enable tags for that post type? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245071/show-tag-panel-in-custom-post-type

Comment: Posts have tags but what I'm wanting to do is have a custom field attached to a page which has a string of tags in it separated by a comma. Then query for posts on that page which have those specific page tags.

Comment: I got ya. Well you could try explode() on that field (which I would advise against) which would break the string into an array. You would use the comma as the delimiter. The problem would be that your database query would retrieve every post and then explode() each time that field is encountered.  Have you thought about custom taxanomies for that post? It's very similar to tags. The benefit would be that the functionality is built into wordpress. http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/05/06/custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress-28

Comment: Are these better than tags at all? I currently have tags in each post. Is there any better way of doing it rather than having a custom field on the page? Is there a way I can do it via templates etc?

Comment: A Category, Tag, Link Category and Post Format are all built in taxonomies in Wordpress. The benefit of a custom taxonomy meta box added to your post type would be that you could name it "Countries". Plus you could use both your tags and your Countries taxonomy for doing different types of queries.

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

```
function people_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'countries',
        'post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Countries' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'countries' ),
            'capabilities' => array(
                'assign_terms' => 'edit_guides',
                'edit_terms' => 'publish_guides'
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'countries_init' );
```